# Recursive Function.prototype.apply conceptual understanding

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I came across [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048388/javascript-recursive-array-flattening) about recursively flattening a JS array. Here is the accepted answer:

```
function flatten() {
    var flat = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (arguments[i] instanceof Array) {
            flat.push.apply(flat, flatten.apply(this, arguments[i]));
        } else {
            flat.push(arguments[i]);
        }
    }
    return flat;
}

flatten([[1], 2, [3, 4]]); // returns [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I'm having trouble understanding how `flat.push.apply(...)` and `flatten.apply(...)` work.

I understand that the function will only exit if *none* of the items in the array are arrays themselves. I also understand that `Function.prototype.apply()` allows you to call a function using an array of arguments.

What I don't understand is why you are using `flat.push...` if `flat` will be set to `[]` at each function iteration. Also, what significance does setting `flat` as the `this` context have?

**Can someone help explain how the execution of `flat.push.apply(flat, flatten.apply(this, arguments[i]));` works?**

Comment: "*if `flat` will be set to `[]` at each function iteration.*" - it's not iteration, it's recursion. And each call does have its own, local variables.

Comment: "*what significance does setting `flat` as the this context have?*" - it's the context for the `push` *method*, which is the array that will be pushed upon. Just like if you regularly invoke `flat.push(…)` *on `flat`*.

Comment: `flat` is not set each iteration, it's only set once, before the loop.

Comment: Then how does the execution stack work for recursion, and how is it different than the execution stack for iteration?

Comment: @Himmel: What do you mean by "execution stack"? Recursion has a *call stack*, iteration (in the sense of imperative repetition, like a `for` loop) doesn't have any.

Comment: why? `r=[];r.push([1]);r;` makes `[[1]]`, whereas `r=[];r.push.apply(r,[1]);r;` makes `[1]`

Comment: @Bergi if you nest a function within another function, the new function that is called is added to the call stack and has it's own execution context. I meant to say "call stack" and not "execution stack".

Comment: @Himmel: Nesting (in the source code) creates scope closures, which are a different kind again. For a call stack, you just need to call any function.

Comment: @dandavis, so the function `flatten` is run a total of 4 times, but flat is only reset to `[]` in each execution context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He uses `flat.push` safely, because `push` is actually called on different array everytime. Each time `flatten` executes, it creates new array with different reference stored in `flat` variable, so each recursion is associated with different `flat` array.

Setting `flat` as `this` context provides the array to be called `push` upon. Try setting it to `null`, and you will probably get `TypeError` because of illegal operation - trying to call `push` on `null`.

Now for the more complicated part. `push` accepts a list of arguments to be added to array, right? But it is sometimes not convenient to supply these arguments one by one, especially, if you don't know, how many of them `push` should receive, as in your case, where the sizes of arrays to be flatten vary.

That's why the author of that code invokes `push` via `apply` with array reference as second argument - which is the returned value of `flatten.apply(this, arguments[i])` - reference to array containing only numbers by that time. Each number of that array is pushed to `flat`, because `apply` called `push` and passed whole list of numbers of that array via arguments to `push`.

The `flatten.apply(this, arguments[i])` part is invoked via `apply` because of similar reasons - it utilizes `arguments` (array-like object each function has) to process function args easily. Handing over `this` in the first arg of `apply` doesn't really matter here, because there is no use for `this` in `flatten` (`this` points to global object in your code sample).