# Time complexity for recrusive deep flatten

Tags: javascript, recursion, big-o

What is the runtime for this recursive flatten function? My guess is that it's linear; can someone explain why?

```
const arr = [
  [14, [45, 60], 6, [47, [1, 2, [14, [45, 60], 6, [47, [1, 2]], 9]]], 9],
];

function flatten(items) {
  const flat = [];

  items.forEach(item => {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      flat.push(...flatten(item));
    } else {
      flat.push(item);
    }
  });

  return flat;
}
```

Comment: I also would think that it's linear in the number of elements, because ultimately you need to touch each element once, as it gets moved to a single level array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30048623/2630817 can take a look?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen although `O(N)` is intuitive, it depends on the recursive structure of the array, since intermediate buffers are being created for each nested array.

Answer (score 11):

As pointed out in the comments, since each element is indeed touched only once, the time complexity is *intuitively* `O(N)`.

However, because each recursive call to `flatten` creates a new intermediate array, the run-time depends strongly on the structure of the input array.

---

A non-trivial<sup>1</sup> example of such a case would be when the array is organized similarly to a full binary tree:

`[[[a, b], [c, d]], [[e, f], [g, h]]], [[[i, j], [k, l]], [[m, n], [o, p]]]`

```
               |
        ______ + ______
       |               |
    __ + __         __ + __
   |       |       |       |
 _ + _   _ + _   _ + _   _ + _
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
```

The time complexity recurrence relation is:

```
T(n) = 2 * T(n / 2) + O(n)
```

Where `2 * T(n / 2)` comes from recursive calls to `flatten` the sub-trees, and `O(n)` from `push`ing<sup>2</sup> the results, which are two arrays of length `n / 2`.

The [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) states that in this case  **`T(N) = O(N log N)`**, not `O(N)` as expected.

<sub>1) *non-trivial* means that no element is wrapped unnecessarily, e.g. `[[[a]]]`.</sub>

<sub>2) This implicitly assumes that `k` push operations are `O(k)` amortized, which is not guaranteed by the standard, but is still true for most implementations.</sub>

---

A "true" `O(N)` solution will directly append to the *final* output array instead of creating intermediate arrays:

```
function flatten_linear(items) {
  const flat = [];
  
  // do not call the whole function recursively
  // ... that's this mule function's job
  function inner(input) {
     if (Array.isArray(input))
        input.forEach(inner);
     else
        flat.push(input);
  }
  
  // call on the "root" array
  inner(items);  

  return flat;
}
```

The recurrence becomes `T(n) = 2 * T(n / 2) + O(1)` for the previous example, which is linear.

<sub>Again this assumes both 1) and 2).</sub>

Comment: how come you chose T(n/b) as T(n/2)?

Comment: @Undefined the time complexity calculations were specific to the example tree-like array structure above (and of course 2 is the smallest possible branching factor); the algorithm itself doesn't assume anything about the structure of the input (bar stupid edge cases like cyclic references)