# How to flatten nested object to an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I need to  flatten nested object to an array of objects. So far this is what i came up with. But it is not working properly. Currently I'm checking the current element is object or not, if it is an object I'm calling same function recursively.

As the output i need this.

```sh
[
 {title: 'Foo', value: 111},
 {title: 'Bar', value: 222},
 ...
]
```

```js
var data = {
  1: {
    title: "Foo",
    value: 111,
    children: {
      2: {
        title: "Bar",
        value: 222,
      },
    },
  },
  3: {
    title: "Baz",
    value: 333,
    children: {
      4: {
        title: "Qux",
        value: 444,
        children: {
          5: {
            title: "Quux",
            value: 555,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

const finalArrayOfObjects = [];

  const flattenObject = (obj) => {
    const flattened = {};

    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
      if (typeof obj[key] === "object" && obj[key] !== null) {
        flattenObject(obj[key]);
      } else {
        flattened[key] = obj[key];
      }

      finalArrayOfObjects.push(flattened);
      console.log(flattened);
    });
  };
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048388/javascript-recursive-array-flattening might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, using a recursive generator function.

```js
var data = {
  1: {
    title: "Foo",
    value: 111,
    children: {
      2: {
        title: "Bar",
        value: 222,
      },
    },
  },
  3: {
    title: "Baz",
    value: 333,
    children: {
      4: {
        title: "Qux",
        value: 444,
        children: {
          5: {
            title: "Quux",
            value: 555,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

function *forAllChildren(obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    let { children, ...objWithoutChildren} = obj[key];
    yield objWithoutChildren;
    yield *forAllChildren(obj[key].children);
  }
}

const result = [...forAllChildren(data)]
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this work for you

```js
var finalArrayOfObjects = [];

var flattenObject = (obj) => {

    for(var key in obj) {
        // { title , value, children}
        var data = obj[key]
        if (data.children) {
            // data.children = { key : {title , value, children} }
            flattenObject(data.children)
        }
        finalArrayOfObjects.push({
            title : data.title,
            value : data.value,
        })
    }
}
flattenObject(data)
console.log(finalArrayOfObjects)
```

Answer (score 0):

Time to once again prove the power of  **Functional Programming & Recursion**

```
var data = {
        1: {
          title: "Foo",
          value: 111,
          children: {
            2: {
              title: "Bar",
              value: 222,
            },
          },
        },
        3: {
          title: "Baz",
          value: 333,
          children: {
            4: {
              title: "Qux",
              value: 444,
              children: {
                5: {
                  title: "Quux",
                  value: 555,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      };

  const dictAsArray = Object.values(data);
  const flat = [];

  function drill(array) {
    array.map(obj => {
       recursiveCall(obj);
      });
   }

  function recursiveCall(obj) {
    if (obj.children) {
      const children = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object.values(obj.children)));
      delete obj.children; 
      drill(children);
    }

    flat.push(obj);
  }

  dictAsArray.map(dict => recursiveCall(dict));
  console.log(flat);
```

In this approach the children objects are removed from each object.
If you would like them to remain though, you can simply remove `delete obj.children`.